# io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostRequestDecoder$ErrorDataDecoderException: Bad string invalid escape sequence

Tags: java, netty

When the http content contains the char *%* ,`io.netty.handler.codec.http.QueryStringDecoder.decodeComponent()` will throw a `IllegalArgumentException` with message: `` invalid escape sequence `%" ...... ``.

Does that mean that the http content cannot contain the char %?
The request param is json str:

```
{"discountRate":"10%"}
```

The detail of the code can not show;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Percent signs have a special meaning in URLs. Literal percent signs need to be encoded as %25 https://www.urlencoder.io/learn/